# Java EE 6 - SEAM + EJB integration / 3 tier architecture

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, n-tier-architecture, seam3

I've been using JSF 2.1 & EJB 3.1. So far, my aplication have such flow:

1. Facelets template
2. @ManagedBean connected to .xhtml page
3. @Stateless EJB bean that uses EntityManager to get entities from DB
   etc
4. EJB bean is injected to @ManagedBean via @EJB

So basically for 1 entity class I have 2 classes and 1 xhtml page.

Now, I'm starting new project with SEAM 3 (solder, faces, security and validation modules). How can I simplify application flow? Can I use EntityManager inside JSF bean and get all EJB functions, like transactions etc? How can I organise my project (entity classes, bean classes, service classes)? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I simplify application flow?

From what you are wrote i don't thinks that you have some complicated architecture.

> Can I use EntityManager inside JSF bean and get all EJB functions,
>   like transactions etc?

If this is possible why should you do that?

> How can I organise my project (entity classes, bean classes, service
>   classes)?

I would say that your application organisation should not be changed.